# Best way to transfer a file from one server to another Server in production environment

Tags: server, architecture, file-storage

I want to store a file uploaded by a user to "File storage" system.

There are two servers , Server-A and Server-B. Server-B is only accessible form Server-A and File Storage system is accessible from Server B only.

I want to store this into "File Storage system. Currently Server-A does not have access to this storage system.

Which is the best way tot achieve this ?

I have tries to send a file in base64 format to server B, But it takes a time when if filesize is quite big. Most of the time filesize is quite big. User has to wait till server process this.

[image]

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific. Are you looking for a tool? A protocol? A library? does server B owns the file storage? What protocols do the file storage, server B, and server A speak?

Comment: I am looking for a best way to handle this with the tool / protocol. Server B has access to FileStorage(NAS).